# Homebrew installation fails

Tags: node.js, homebrew

```
==> Installing dependencies for node: libnghttp2, libuv, ca-certificates and openssl@1.1
==> Installing node dependency: libnghttp2
==> Pouring libnghttp2-1.48.0.arm64_monterey.bottle.tar.gz
Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/lky/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/01903ff762254112edcbfc63f384af2c616deb9c819dbc96f092d5078049404e--libnghttp2-1.48.0.arm64_monterey.bottle.tar.gz
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: try run `brew doctor` and `brew config`, it would help with the debugging.